# Lambda failed with error grpc_extension.js:38:15

Tags: aws-lambda

I have added npm gcloud to my Lambda project and it fails immediately when my Lambda function starts, I think it as something with the node version but I could't find any resolution

Error:

`module initialization error: Error at Error (native) 
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18) 
at Module.load (module.js:343:32) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) 
at Module.require (module.js:353:17) 
at require (internal/module.js:12:17) 
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/grpc_extension.js:38:15) 
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)`

my dependencies:

```
    "amqplib": "^0.4.2",
    "async": "^2.0.0-rc.6",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.4.4",
    "dogapi": "^2.3.0",
    "elasticsearch": "^11.0.1",
    "elasticsearch-streams": "0.0.9",
    "gcloud": "^0.37.0",
    "googleapis": "^9.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "util": "^0.10.3"
```

Comment: Hello Avi. I was wondering if you had any luck so far, as Google said they will add support from 1.0. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6443

Answer (score 1):

It seems some node packages uses pre-compiled binary. So it needs to be compiled on a target platform, Amazon Linux AMI in your case. You can create Amazon EC2 instance put your project on it, run `npm i`, zip it and download on your pc, then upload archive on Lambda.